# Ionic 3 - ion-select(multiple) disable all options after selecting two items

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to disable all options once two options checked. I have tried `(ionChange)` but this event fired after clicking the "Ok" button of the select model. Is there any other event which execute before "ionChange"?

[image: disable]

```
 <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Values</ion-label>
     <ion-select formControlName="Values" multiple="true">
          <ion-option value="1">1 value</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="2">2 value</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="3">3 value</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="4">4 value</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="5">5 value</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: If you need to add some custom logic, maybe using a modal (with some css style rules to make it look *like an alert*) would be a better option.

Comment: Hi @shah.

Did you ever get an answer to this? Because I am faced with the very same problem

Answer (score 2):

Below code will satisfy your requirement. Change the check box limit to increase or decrease the number of options that can be selection. Tips to optimization is also welcomed.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-radio)

component file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  selectedIng : Array<any>=[];
  numberOfChecks : number=1;
  checkBoxLimit : any =1;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.pizzaIng=[
      {name : "Pepperoni", checked : false},
      {name : "Sasuage", checked : true},
      {name : "Mushrooms", checked : false}
    ];
    this.selectedIng=[{name : "Sasuage", checked : true}];    
  }

  updateIng(ing){
      if(ing.checked === true){
      this.selectedIng.push(ing);
      this.numberOfChecks++;
      }else{
        this.selectedIng=this.pizzaIng.filter((ingr)=>{
          console.log(ingr['checked'])
          return ingr['checked']===true;
        })
        this.numberOfChecks--;
      }

    console.log(this.selectedIng);
    console.log(this.numberOfChecks);
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item  *ngFor="let ing of pizzaIng; let i = index">
    <ion-label>{{ing.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="ing.checked"  [disabled]="ing.checked==false && numberOfChecks>=checkBoxLimit"  (ionChange)="updateIng(ing)"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: This is not what i want. I am looking for `<ion-select formControlName="Values" multiple="true">` events. The property binding `[disabled]` will not work for that.

Comment: I thought you are asking for check box but it's simple to convert with this I guess. Maybe I will try a sample after sometime

Answer (score 1):

Use `[disabled]` property in on-change function You can perform disable action and other functionality using the selected value